# getting error while executing mongo command

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoid

I have a created a collection with following command:

`db.device_states.documentKey.insert({"device":"nest_kitchen_thermo"})`

When I try to execute below command I get an error:

```
db.device_states.watch( {
     $match: {
             "documentKey.device": {
                   $in : [ "nest_kitchen_thermo"]
             },
             operationType: "insert"
     }
});
```

> syntax ERROR: missing:after property id:

The updated collection looks like that:

```
{ 
    _id: <resume_token>,
    operationType: 'insert',
    ns: {db:'example',coll:"device_states"},
    documentKey: { device:'nest_kitchen_thermo'},
    fullDocument: { 
       _id : ObjectId(),
       device: 'nest_kitchen_thermo',
       temp: 68
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question @niroopsainni? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: my question is db.device_states.watch( {...}) througing error i am wrong in creating the collection,please help me to create the collection to work my db.device_states.watch( { ..)} query properly.

Comment: ive got no idea about mongoose, i just point that your post is totally not readable. If you want to get some atention the least you can do is make your question clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mongo shell, there is no such querying attribute `watch`. [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) is part of aggregation pipeline and it should be used within the aggregate operation.

Modified query(Mongo Shell) is

```
db.device_states.documentKey.aggregate([
  { $match:
    { 
      "device": { $in: ["nest_kitchen_thermo"] }, 
      operationType: "insert"
    }
  }
]);
```